# Как отслеживать изменения в регулярно удаляемой таблице?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть таблица, и вместо того чтобы ее апдейтить, мои прекрасные коллеги ее полностью удаляют и на ее место заливают обновленную. Изменения могут быть как добавлением, так и изменением существующих полей.

Мне нужно отслеживать изменения, но как вы понимаете, из-за удаления, через trigger это невозможно.

Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно отследить изменения? я хочу написать процедуру, которая будет следить за изменениями и заливать новую инфу в новую похожую табличку, на которую я уже и напишу триггер.

как я вижу.

1.**каким-то способом отследить изменения**

2. по факту изменения апдейтнуть мою новую таблицу
3. на апдейт новой таблицы написать триггер , чтобы сохранить старые данные.

Comment: А отслеживать надо только изменения структуры таблицы? Невзирая на данные в ней?

Comment: Данные тоже нужны, чтобы перезалить их в новую таблицу. я думала сделать как:  вычислить что таблица изменилась, апдейтнуть свою аналогичную таблицу, и по своей уже сделать триггер чтобы потом следить что меняется.

Comment: короче отслеживать нужно что угодно. столбец\поле появились или какое-то поле изменилось.

Comment: То есть, Ваша новая таблица содержит не только "последнюю версию структуры", но и все данные за всю историю сущствования исходной таблицы? я вижу здесь две проблемы: пусть в исходной таблице есть auto increment primary key. ТОгда при каждом удалении - создании исходной таблицы нумерация в этом поле будет начинаться сначала. Соответсвенно, для таблицы с аккумулированными данными это уже не будет PK. Втора проблема - пусть в исходной таблице переименовали, поменяв местам, два поля. Непонятно, как такое изменение структуры учесть...

Comment: При изменении поля может поменяться и тип этого поля. Для новых данных в той таблице, котрая исходная, это будет нормальный тип. А для "старых" данных - непонятно, что с ними делать.

Comment: моя новая таблица будет отображать только актуальную инфу(апдейтится вместе со старой) я думала сделать 3ью таблицу для записи логов. 

Изменения в таблице будут без изменений типов данных самого столбца. там либо будет меняться стотлбец даты с NULL на дату, либо меняться на другую.

Comment: в таблице так же отстутсвует PRIMARY KEY. есть лишь номер заявки, бывает что по одной заявке несколько строк, так что эта ситуция с праймари ки- не проблемная

Comment: Прошу прощения, я читаю последовательно вопрос и комментарии к нему, и не могу въехать в задачу. Когда исходную таблицу грохают - данные, котрые грохнули вместе с ней - уже не представляют ценности? Или представляют?

Comment: скорее нет чем да

Comment: А какую тогда ценность представляет отслеживание и копирование в другую таблицу? Смотрите в исходную: пока данные есть - хорошо, работаем с ними. Их не стало? Но по предыдущему комментарию - они же в этом случае уже не представляют ценности. Может, все таки в формулировке задачи что то не очень понятно?

Comment: вообще да, простите. ценность все же имеют. ну тут какая ситуация. таблицу удалили. залили новую, нужно бы сохранить и то что было до, и то что новое. как я вижу. каким-то способом отследить изменения, по факту изменения апдейтнуть мою новую таблицу, и от апдейта новой таблицы написать триггер чтобы сохранить старые данные. 

Основной вопрос задачи как это дело отследить

Comment: Получается задачка на DDL-триггер. По факту удаления таблицы - заменять удаление на переименование либо делать копию, по факту вставки в новую таблицу в копии делать пометку о существовании и копировать в неё отсутствующие записи.

Comment: а как можно сделать триггер на удаление то? не понимаю

Comment: [DDL Triggers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/ddl-triggers?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: А вообще, вам бы обсудить всё это дело с коллегами. Если не будет достигнуто понимание, то с начальством. Если и там не будет понимания, то рассмотреть возможность ухода с той работы.